# How to put square brackets and a subscript next to each other in R expression?

Tags: r

Here is my problem: for a plot label, I need to have a letter in square brackets ([M]) and a subscript right next to it. The normal way of making a subscript with expression function doesn't work:

```
expression(paste("[M]",[P]))
```

returns an error - apparently it wants to have something in front of the subscript, because this way -

```
expression(M[P])
```

it works.

Does anybody know how to overcome this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
expression("[M]"[P])
```

An example:

```
plot(1, main = expression("[M]"[P]))
```

[image]

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I suppose the string in the quotation marks is evaluated first, then the subscript is applied.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks a million. All the expression() syntax seems really confusing to me, I wish there would be a way to introduce LATEX expressions into R code directly. Anyway, thanks again for the fast reply.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg It's not illformed: you're trying to index the Pth item in a character vector consisting only of the string "[M]": it's equivalent to `"a"[1]`